# Blocking inspector on any web browser

Tags: css

If you go to this site http://www.tackleplumbing.ca I cannot view the source or the divs if I right click on my mouse in Chrome or firefox.

It will not give me any information I would like to do this for my own websites that I design.

Is there a code for this and do I have to insert it into each page?

Thank you.

Comment: There is absolutely no way of blocking users from using Inspector or even accessing your source code once you put it online.

Comment: You can still use the menu to go to Tools->View Source, or hit F12. Are you trying to hide the source for your page (not possible other than not publishing your website), or do you specifically want to swallow right-click events to prevent a context menu from showing up?

Answer (score 0):

Try to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd>  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd>  <kbd>I</kbd>

Or simply press <kbd>F12</kbd>

(Assuming you are using windows and chrome)